# Full Outer Join in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am trying to do a full outer join on two collections. Given `collection1` with a document that looks like this:

```
{
id: 234982032,
name: example,
listId: 123
}
```

and `collection2` with a document that looks like this:

```
{
id: 123,
description: desc1
}
```

I expect a result like this:

```
{
id: 234982032,
name: example,
description: desc1
}
```

I have tried using this command:

`fq={!join from=listId to=id fromIndex=collection2}description:desc1`

but this results in only in inner join. Is there a way I can outer join two collections using a filter query? If this is not a possible Is there a plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [join using the join query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) (i.e. `{!join}`) in Solr can't retrieve content from both sides of the join. These are purely inner joins, where one field is used for filtering content from the collection being queried.

> This is different from the concept of a join in a relational database because no information is being truly joined. An appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".

If you're on a recent-ish version of Solr you do have another option, which is [using a Streaming Expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/streaming-expressions.html).

This will allow you to [set up two stream sources](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/stream-source-reference.html#stream-source-reference), then apply either [a leftOuterJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/stream-decorator-reference.html#leftouterjoin) or [an outerHashJoin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/stream-decorator-reference.html#outerhashjoin) to get a document with combined information from both sides.

From the example in the reference guide:

```
leftOuterJoin(
  search(people, q="*:*", qt="/export", fl="personId,name", sort="personId asc"),
  search(pets, q="type:cat", qt="/export", fl="personId,petName", sort="personId asc"),
  on="personId"
)

outerHashJoin(
  search(people, q="*:*", qt="/export", fl="personId,name", sort="personId asc"),
  hashed=search(pets, q="type:cat", qt="/export", fl="personId,petName", sort="personId asc"),
  on="personId"
)
```

Replace `pets` and `people` with `collection1` and `collection2` from your question. Be aware that you must have a `sort` criteria that maps the key used for joining when using the `leftOuterJoin`, but this usually makes the join more efficient for larger result sizes, since the outerHashJoin has to keep a lot more in memory.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh, this worked for me. Does this work for nested documents too? I've been trying to apply filters in addition to the `leftOuterJoin` to maintain the nested structure of the document, but was unable to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with nested documents at all.

Comment: Hi bro @MatsLindh. Sorry for very late comment now. I have a question about pagination stream expression. Is there any chance for it now?

Comment: @DucAnhPham Create a proper question if you have a question